# How to make a query to different collections (without relationships)?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to increase performance of a query execution.
MongoDB contain three (or more) collections with documents that have same strucre. Something like that:

```
db.france.insertMany([
    {field1: 11, field2: 12, field3: 13},
    {field1: 21, field2: 22, field3: 23},
    {field1: 31, field2: 32, field3: 33}
])

db.germany.insertMany([
    {field1: 11, field2: 12, field3: 13},
    {field1: 21, field2: 22, field3: 23},
    {field1: 31, field2: 32, field3: 33}
])

db.belgium.insertMany([
    {field1: 11, field2: 12, field3: 13},
    {field1: 21, field2: 22, field3: 23},
    {field1: 31, field2: 32, field3: 33}
])
```

What should be the query (one query) to get the result like this from two collecitons "france" and "germany":

```
[
    {field1: 21, field2: 22, field3: 23},
    {field1: 21, field2: 22, field3: 23}    
]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What will be your matching condition? When you lookup in two collections on some basis you need mapping right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` if you want to search specific document field
- `$group` by null and prepare an array of france documents
- `$lookup` to with gernamny collection and get all documents
- `$project` to concat both arrays document in root using `$concatArrays`
- `$unwind` deconstruct root array
- `$replaceWith` to replace root object in root

```
db.france.aggregate([
  // { $match: { field1: 21 } } // optional
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      france: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "germany",
      pipeline: [
        // { $match: { field1: 21 } } // optional
      ],
      as: "germany"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      root: {
        $concatArrays: ["$france", "$germany"]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $replaceWith: "$root" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hAWthvPgitM)

> Note: If you have millions of records in both collections then i am not suggesting you to use this query, might be this query would be heavy in speed and efficiency, you need to change your schema design or you can execute 2 queries and combine both results.

Comment: Great job! As I realize the aggregation execute query and result hold in pipeline (and clear RAM), next do other query and add to pipeline (again clear RAM), and concat arrays of results.

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid there is no straight forward solution for this. You would have to manually merge the two documents in your server.

But in this case I would say its more of a schema design problem. In this case I would recommend you to store all the documents in a single collection. Then simply add a `country` field.

Then you can easily query your documents with the following query:

`Coll.find({ country: { $in: ["france", "germany"], field1: 21, field2: 22, field3:23  })`

Comment: This data just for example. The DB in production may contain millions documents.